# Missing AVDs during debug in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-virtual-device

I'm developing a widget with the following *Sdk* settings in *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```xml
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

I've defined some devices with android 4.0.3 (Intel), some with 2.3.3 (both Arm and Intel) and I have also a physical device at 4.0.4:
[image: Devined Android Virtual Devices]

When I try to debug my widget app, the only available devices (running or that can be started) are the devices at 4.0.3 and 4.0.4. I tried to manually start from AVD Manager one of the devices at 2.3.3 and then it showed up in the list of the running devices, but with a red X that (I think) means there is some problem:
[image]

I can debug then the app on the 2.3.3 device, but I'm experiencing some problems (not yet investigated)... Can you tell me a possible reason for AVDs not showing up in the debug window?

If I create another blank project with `targetSdkVersion=10` all the devices are shown, but they should be shown also in my project, given the `minSdkVersion="8"`, right?

Answer (score 1):

The AVDs aren't showing up in the "Choose a running Android device" panel because they haven't started yet. You need to manually start the AVDs on your computer to run your app on them. Another option is to have it set up to start an AVD automatically when you want to run the app and no devices are connected, but that can get in the way sometimes.

Also, the red X there is usually because you're building for an Android version that's above the version that the device is running.

Comment: The "problem" is the *Build Target* of the Project.. since it is set to 4.0.3, it show only 4.0.3 devices.. if I lower down to 2.3.3, then all the devices are shown in the bottom part of the Debug window.. Shouldn't it show all the devices supported by the app, i.e. from sdk level 8 to 15?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only thing that helped was an upgrade of ADT/SDK. If you do want to test your app, start the emulator in the AVD manager and wait for it to start up. Then you will be able to select it when pressing "run".

The red X is not a problem. It just means that it doesn't meet the build target of the app. Which... if you are developing, you should be targeting the highest version.